# how can i parse a list of JSON objects using Javascript / Node or React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the response that i get from the backend:

```
[{
  "model": "G7",
  "brand": "LG",
  "price": 999.99,
  "image": "https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Products/LG-G7-ThinQ?INT=MOB_mobdevpg_BTN_poplink_Mass_051016_mb_details#",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "model": "P20 Pro",
  "brand": "Huawei",
  "price": 1200,
  "image": "https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Products/Huawei-P20-Pro?INT=MOB_mobdevpg_BTN_poplink_Mass_051016_mb_details#",
  "id": 2
}]
```

Here is the React code that i use to fetch data:

```
fetchData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/allProducts', {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(parsedJson => parsedJson.results)
      .then(products => this.setState({
        products
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log('error fetching data', err))
  }
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: Why dont you accept one of the answers? دیوس بوزینه؟ الاغ الاف گیر اوردی؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `axios` you can achieve it like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/allProducts', {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    }
})
  .then(res => callback(res))
```

`callback` is a function and you can access json data from `res.data`

Although I think that the access control header should be set on the server and should be on response header not on request header.

If you own the server and are using `express` add this middleware to your backend:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your Products data from backend:

```
[{
    "model": "G7",
    "brand": "LG",
    "price": 999.99,
    "image": "https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Products/LG-G7-ThinQ?INT=MOB_mobdevpg_BTN_poplink_Mass_051016_mb_details#",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "model": "P20 Pro",
    "brand": "Huawei",
    "price": 1200,
    "image": "https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Products/Huawei-P20-Pro?INT=MOB_mobdevpg_BTN_poplink_Mass_051016_mb_details#",
    "id": 2
}]
```

Then you should going each product example:

```
function productProcess(products) {
    products.forEach(product => {
        const { model, brand, price, image, id } = product;
        console.log('model:', model);
        //Example:
        // this.setState({
        //    id: { model, brand, price, image },
        // })
    });
}

fetchData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/allProducts', {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parsedJson => parsedJson.results)
    .then(productProcess)
    .catch(err => console.log('error fetching data', err))
}
```

Comment: I found how to fix this error, in fact the reason I could not fetch the data is the following error:
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
and to fix that, you can install a CHROME extension (Allow-Control-Allow-Origin) that helps you to bypass this error, the extention sometimes doesn't work properly so you have to reinstall it